# cycling images in jQuery - randomize it?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-cycle

I've got a site that has a div that has some images:

```
 <div class="slideshow">
            <img src="lib/images/grid/slideshow/a-960x305/a_pic1.jpg" width="960" height="305" alt="1" class="first" />
            <img src="lib/images/grid/slideshow/a-960x305/a_pic2.jpg" width="960" height="305" alt="2" />
            <img src="lib/images/grid/slideshow/a-960x305/a_pic3.jpg" width="960" height="305" alt="3" />
            <img src="lib/images/grid/slideshow/a-960x305/a_pic4.jpg" width="960" height="305" alt="4" />
  </div>
```

Notice the first image has a class name called first.  This is so the page only shows one image at a time via css:

Here's the CSS:

```
/*begin slideshow*/
div.slideshow                              { margin:0 0 5px 0; /*height:305px;*/ } /*for the jQuery cycle plug in*/
div.slideshow img                          { display:none;}
div.slideshow img.first                    { display:block;}
.caption                                   { text-align:center; font-weight:bold; color:#1F7FB6;}
/*end slideshow*/
```

I am using the jquery cycle library to cycle through the images like so:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.slideshow').cycle({
                fx: 'fade', // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
                timeout: 7000,
                after: function () {
                    $('.caption').html(this.alt);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The issue is the page will of course always start with the first image, is there a way to randomize this a bit so that it can start a random image rather then always starting with `a_pic1.jpg` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

set the `random` to `1` in the jQuery cycle [options](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html)

> random:        0,     // true for random, false for sequence (not applicable to shuffle fx)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'fade', // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
        timeout: 7000,
        after: function () {
            $('.caption').html(this.alt);
        },
        random: 1 // <-- add this
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the cycle library, but a here is an example using an array:

```
<script>

var banners = new Array("#banner1","#banner2","#banner3","#banner4");

var counter = //random number between 0-3;

$(document).ready(function()
{
    nextBanner();
});


function nextBanner()
{
    var currentBanner = counter;
    counter++;

    if (counter > banners.length -1)
    {
        counter = 0;
    }
    $( banners[currentBanner] ).fadeOut(300 );
    setTimeout('$( banners[counter] ).fadeIn( 300)', 100);
    setTimeout("nextBanner()", 9000);
}

</script>

<div id="banner1" class="banner-item">      
    <img src="/banner1.jpg" />
</div>

<div id="banner2" class="banner-item" style="display: none;">       
    <img src="banner2.jpg" />
</div>
```

..

The css

```
.banner-item
{
    position: absolute; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this? I haven't tried to run this but you get the idea.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.slideshow img').get(random()*($('.slideshow img').length-1)).addClass('first');
        $('.slideshow').cycle({
        ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Before making your `.cycle()` call you could do something like this:

```
var images = $('.slideshow > img');
images.get(0).removeClass("first");
images.get(Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)).addClass("first");
```

Answer (score 0):

Leave off the class='first' bit, and then run this code to randomize the image that gets class="first"

```
$(function(){
   var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.slideshow img').length);

   $('.slideshow img').eq(rnd).addClass("first");           
});
```